# Однокоренные слова к словам "гости", "сухарь"

Tags: однокоренные-слова, общие-вопросы

Помогите подобрать однокоренные слова к словам "гости", "сухарь".

Answer (score 1):

Гость, гостевой, гостить, гостиница, угощать. Сухой, сушить,  сухарь, сушильный, сушняк.

Answer (score 1):

1. гостинец, гостеприимный, гастарбайтер:)
2. сушь, сухостой

Answer (score 0):

Гости - гостить, гостиница, гостиный, загостился, гостья.
Сухарь - сухарик, сухарница, сухарня.